# Where to find advanced stats like PER and Win Shares for Division 1 College Basketball players in the NCAA?

Tags: basketball, statistics, collegiate, sabermetrics

Is there any comprehensive centralised online resource where I can find advanced stats/metrics for free or at least relatively inexpensive?

At a minimum I would like to start with Player Efficiency Rating (PER) or Adjusted Efficiency Rating.

Then ideally I would move onto Box Plus/Minus (BPM), Value Over Replacement Player (VORP) and True Shooting Percentage (TS%). This would be just for the top NCAA players of the previous season who were drafted in the 1st round of the NBA draft.

So far I've looked in:

https://cbbanalytics.com/

https://www.teamrankings.com/ncaa-basketball/player-stat/win-score

And of course Sports Reference which only shows the all-time best players in PER: https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/leaders/men/per-player-career.html

So unfortunately none of these sources have turned out to be very useful, so any help in this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!